# Django models, How to retrieve a property of a foreign key object

Tags: django

I have a class like this

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
```

another class

```
class Properties(models.Model):

    description = models.CharField()
    product =  models.ForeignKey(Product)
```

in the **str** function of the properties class I want to use the object product and its atributes.

```
 def __str__(self):
    p = Product.objects.get(Product)
    return p.name
```

Somehow it doesnt work,

If I just return the 'Product' it shows  so it is the object itself, how can I access the atributes then?

Comment: `self.product.name`

Answer (score 1):

As @2ps says in comments:

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.product.name
```

See [docs.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/instances/#str)